# Are there any complete lists of made-for-tv Lifetime movies?

Tags: scheduling

Specifically, I'm looking for a schedule or list of all made-for-tv Lifetime movies that have premiered to date, in 2015. Is there some hidden calendar or schedule on their website? Can this information be found elsewhere?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but there may be other lists on IMDb that are helpful to you: http://www.imdb.com/company/co0006395/?ref_=fn_al_co_3

Comment: Or this one... Lifetime Movie Network: http://www.imdb.com/company/co0044403/?ref_=fn_al_co_4

Comment: @Catja I had found a similar link earlier today, but it wasn't very good... however, yours is 95%+ of what I need (the IMDB one). If you make it an answer I'd be more than happy to accept it. I'm wondering if I found that Lifetime Movie Network page instead of the main channel's...

Comment: @Catja Oh, wow... this must be it. They seem to have one new movie per week, which sort of makes sense, no skips or gaps. Thank you much, I was thinking I'd have to poke around on Wikipedia for the next 3 weeks.

Comment: Even wiki have it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lifetime_(TV_network)_films